# npm install serialport needs VS?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, electron

I have been trying to install serialport for an electron project, but whenever I make use of
`npm install serialport`, I end up with the following error

```
E:\Windows\Desktop\Work\Electron\testing>npm install serialport

> @serialport/bindings@8.0.7 install E:\Windows\Desktop\Work\Electron\testing\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
> prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=13.6.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

E:\Windows\Desktop\Work\Electron\testing\node_modules\@serialport\bindings>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.4.29709.97) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Windows\Desktop\Work\Electron\testing\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
gyp ERR! node -v v13.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN testing@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN testing@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @serialport/bindings@8.0.7 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@8.0.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-11T08_43_12_018Z-debug.log
```

Reading through the errors, I saw that they tried to make use of VS, but that got me wondering as to why it needed VS to begin with. I went through the docs of serialport and they stated nothing about prerequisites other than having python2 for gyp, which I already do have added to the path.
It would be a great help if you guys could help me work around this error.

I'm currently making use of V13.6.0 of Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the logs, I realized that serialport was not the thing that was in need of VS. 
When serialport is to be installed, it checks for the node version currently in use and then it is built according to that.
To do something like that, node makes use of what is called gyp, which makes use of python2 and visual studio's C++ dev env to make the required changes,
[more on node-gyp](http://%20https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows). After installing that, everything seemed to have run smoothly.

Just thought saying it here would be handy for someone if they ever came across a small issue like this... ^^

Comment: how to install visual studio's C++ dev env ? is it like installing the whole visual studio application ?